# Java Multithreading, Thread.sleep pauses current thread but wont continue other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm practicing my self with Object Pool Design Pattern with Java. and created sample and tried to run my code.

Program provides limited number of Object in pool and run numbers of asynchronous processes.

My code simply pick up one object from pool (create new if there is no available and objects' count is less than the limit) and return if after `Thread.sleep`. but somehow other threads keeps on looping and couldn't find any available object.

```java
public abstract class ObjectPool<T> {

    private long waitingTime;
    private int maxObjectPoolSize;

    private final List<T> available = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    private final List<T> inUse = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    protected AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private AtomicBoolean waiting = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public abstract T create();

    public ObjectPool(int poolSize) {
        waitingTime = 1200;
        setMaxObjectPoolSize(poolSize);
    }

    public void setMaxObjectPoolSize(int poolSize) {
        this.maxObjectPoolSize = poolSize;
    }

    public synchronized T getObject() {
        if (!available.isEmpty()) {
            T o = available.remove(0);
            inUse.add(o);
            return o;
        }
        // if max pool size, wait for object to be released
        if(count.get() == maxObjectPoolSize) {
            this.waitUntilNextAvailable();
            return this.getObject();
        }
        // if no objects available, create new one
        T o = this.create();
        this.inUse.add(o);
        return o;
    }

    public synchronized void releaseObject(T o) {
        this.inUse.remove(o);
        this.available.add(o);
        System.out.println(o.toString() + " is free");
    }

    private void waitUntilNextAvailable() {
//        if (waiting.get()) {
//            waiting.set(false);
//            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("No Object Available");
//        }
//        waiting.set(true);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        waiting(waitingTime);
    }

    public void waiting(long ms) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class ProcessThread implements Runnable {

    private RoomPool pool;

    public ProcessThread(RoomPool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        takeAnObject();
    }

    private void takeAnObject() {
        try {
            System.out.println("New process: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Room room = pool.getObject();

            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(randInt(1000, 1500));

            pool.releaseObject(room);
            System.out.println("executed: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ObjectNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(">>>> Process Rejected: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }

    private static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        return new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static final int OBJECT_POOL_SIZE = 4;

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RoomPool pool = new RoomPool(OBJECT_POOL_SIZE);
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES; i++) {
            Runnable process = new ProcessThread(pool);
            Thread thread = new Thread(process);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

```
New process: Thread-5
New process: Thread-8
New process: Thread-3
New process: Thread-0
New process: Thread-4
New process: Thread-6
New process: Thread-7
New process: Thread-2
New process: Thread-1
New process: Thread-9
Room name = Room 1 is created
Room name = Room 2 is created
Room name = Room 3 is created
Room name = Room 4 is created
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-7
Thread-7
```

I can't figure out why the threads wont return the objects on pool.

I tried to debug it on my IDE and I saw after the thread being in SLEEP state, it goes to MONITOR after. I'm new to this multithreading thing so I don't know if this is normal.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well I don't see "is free" or "executed" in your run output, so either `sleep()` never returns or `releaseObject()` never returns.

Comment: Also I don't think we have your current code because I don't see were "is created" gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made the `ObjectPool`'s methods synchronized.

Meaning no thread can "release" an object (`synchronized releaseObject(T o)` if there is any thread already "getting" an object `synchronized getObject()`.

Instead of making the whole methods synchronized, you should find a way to make just the modifications of inUse/available atomic.

Try removing the synchronized from the "getObject" and instead synchronize just the first addition/removal from the lists, like so:

```
public T getObject() {
    if (!available.isEmpty()) {
        synchronized(this) {
            T o = available.remove(0);
            inUse.add(o);
        }
        return o;
    }
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks! Synchronizing just the modification of list worked.

Answer (score 2):

One thread is calling `getObject()` in a continuous recursion. Because this thread holds the lock on the pool (`getObject()` is synchronized), no thread can ever return an object to the pool (because `releaseObject()` is synchronized).

When implementing a pool, use concurrent data structures that do not block the release of resources. A release should always be non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Here the case of ojbect locking comes into the picture . when the thread(abc) will call the **synchronized** getobject() for n times . it will hold the lock so that until that time no thread will be able to access the **synchronized** getRelease() method. checkout the below ways to create the object pool.

**OR**

You can use java blocking Queue to create the object pool . blocking Queue is thread safe also.

**OR**

Refer below link to create the object pool 
https://dzone.com/articles/generic-and-concurrent-object